# How to Get IBM jdk7 for Windows(similar to sun/oracle)

Tags: eclipse, maven, sdk, java-7, ibm-jdk

Followed the link to get the IBM jdk7 :

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/

but found that IBM provides jdk for windows integrated with the eclipse(Luna) present inside the package : IBM Development Package for Eclipse downloaded from the site.

It will be really helpful if some one could pin point me to a IBM jdk similar to Sun/Oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IBM Java 7 for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697656/how-to-get-ibm-java-7-for-windows)

Comment: IBM does not provide a JDK without strings attached.  Especially not for Windows.

Comment: What strings are attached to JDK downloads?  IBM's J9 is available on the download page and on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/ibmjava/

Answer (score 0):

The IBM JDK download page has moved to: https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/

For Windows, the JDK is available as part of the "IBM Development package for Eclipse": https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/downloads/#tab_eclipse and not as a separate download.

It is possible to extract the JDK back out of the eclipse package...

Comment: @DanHeidinga..don't think so that it can be extracted..but referencing it directly to the JAVA_HOME path worked for me..as I only wanted to test one of my application for few days due client requirement.